# Is it possible to express an integral equation inside of a convolution

Tags: integration, soft-question, convolution

Given $$u(t) = \int_0^t  y(\tau) d\tau$$

Consider a convolution type of integral

$$W = \int_0^t\lambda^{t-\tau}y(\tau) d\tau$$

$\lambda$ a positive real number

> Is it possible to write $W = f(u(t))$, where $f$ is some/any function?
>
> i.e. is it possible to find $f$?

Comment: if you want that $f$ independent of $y$ and $t$: i doubt that. otherwise trivially $f(x):=u(t)-x+W$ does it.

Comment: i'd be interested in what made you think about this question: is it an excercise from a book or did you find yourself stuck with that while solving something else?

Comment: @Max Thank you for your interest, I am writing something which I defined $u$ as above. But then I considered general case when the integral is weighted by $\lambda$ as shown above, I wonder if I could express this succinctly as $f \circ u$, where $f$ is some function

Comment: by taking derivatives i end up with $f'(u(t))\cdot (y(t)+\int_{0}^{t}(t-\tau)\lambda^{t-1-\tau}y(\tau)\mathrm{d}\tau)=y(t)$ - this does not look very promising

Comment: most probably it's easier too look for counterexamples. what happens for $y$ constant, linear, ...,  powers of $\lambda$ , .....? i think this would be the way to go first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, I don't see how you can get $W(t)$ as a composed function of $u(t)$ as $W(t) = f\left(u(t)\right)$, but you can do the following, which may be of some use:

Assuming $y(t)$ is a sufficiently-smooth function, note that
$$
u(0) = 0
$$
and
$$
u'(t) = y(t)\, .
$$
Plug the latter expression for $y(t)$ into your integral for $W(t)$:
$$
W(t) = \int_0^{\tau} d\tau\, \lambda^{t-\tau} u'(\tau)
$$
Integrate this by parts once to yield:
\begin{align}
W(t) &=
{\left.\lambda^{t-\tau} u(\tau)\right|}_{\tau = 0}^{\tau = t} + \ln\lambda\int_0^t d\tau\, \lambda^{t-\tau} u(\tau) \\
&= u(t) + \ln\lambda\int_0^t d\tau\, \lambda^{t-\tau} u(\tau)\, .
\end{align}
This gives us $W(t)$ as a functional of $u(t)$, but not as a function. I doubt such a function exists for general $y(t)$.